# Is there a function to take this text file format and turn it into a 2d list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a sample of my text file:

What is the 1st planet from the sun? : Mercury
What is the 2nd planet from the sun? : Venus
What is the 3rd planet from the sun? : Earth

I'm trying to find an efficient way to call the question and answer which can be parsed from each line. My thoughts are converting this to a list, and then a 2d list, however each method I trying isn't available. Any ideas on how I should do this?

```
import re

f = open("C:/Users/PatrickStar/Desktop/Trivia_practice.txt", "r")
file_contents = f.read()
file_contents = file_contents.split("\n")

print(file_contents[0])
f.close()
```

Comment: On the face of it you can just split each line at the `:` character.

Comment: Use a for loop with readline() to read line by line and then split by the colon (`:`) character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use list comprehension to split against the colon and created a nested list

```
file_contents = file_contents.split("\n")
# ['What is the 1st planet from the sun? :Mercury', 'What is the 2nd planet from the sun? :Venus', 'What is the 3rd planet from the sun? :Earth']
file_contents = [x.split(':') for x in file_contents]
# nested list where file_contents[i][0] is question and file_contents[i][1] is answer
# [['What is the 1st planet from the sun? ', 'Mercury'], ['What is the 2nd planet from the sun? ', 'Venus'], ['What is the 3rd planet from the sun? ', 'Earth']]
```

Edit: same thing without list comprehension if you're unfamiliar with that

```
file_contents = file_contents.split("\n")
# ['What is the 1st planet from the sun? :Mercury', 'What is the 2nd planet from the sun? :Venus', 'What is the 3rd planet from the sun? :Earth']
2d_contents = []
for x in file_contents:
    2d_contents.append(x.split(':'))
file_contents = 2d_contents
# nested list where file_contents[i][0] is question and file_contents[i][1] is answer
# [['What is the 1st planet from the sun? ', 'Mercury'], ['What is the 2nd planet from the sun? ', 'Venus'], ['What is the 3rd planet from the sun? ', 'Earth']]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution suggested in the comments, you can also avoid the explicit `close` call and the need to parse the lines using `with` and `readlines`:

```
with open("trivia_practice.txt", "r") as f:
    qa = [line.rstrip().split(" :") for line in f.readlines()]
```